# Trying to combine two Xcode projects, error architecture i386

Tags: xcode, exit, i386

Im trying to combine two Xcode projects. I bought these two projects from the web and i want to create a new project with functions from both the projects i bought. The problem is that as soon as I try to drag and drop the .h, .m and .xib (+frameworks) into a new project, it won't work. It usually gives me the error architecture i386 and/or exit code 1. Anyone know how to combine two readymade projects?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's looking for the i386 architecture.  You might want to check `Architectures` in your Build Settings to see if you have i386 listed, and if not, add it.

Comment: it just says standard armv7, armv7s. How do i add i386?

Comment: Just click on standard armv7, and choose "Other..."  then hit the `+` and type i386.